# how to cover Id!=null part in test Class

Tags: apex, unit-test

```
public class democlass{

public string invoiceid{get;set;}

PUBLIC DEMOCLASS(apexpages.standardcontroller controller){

invoiceid=apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id');
**if(invoiceid!=null)
 {
  invoice=[select id,name,net__c,Policy_Status__c,Amount__c,Period__c from invoice_policy__c where id=:invoiceid];

//some code here
}**else{
  invoice=new invoice_policy__C();
}
}
public pagereference saveIn(){
    newinvoicepolicy=new invoice_policy__c();
   **if(invoiceid!=null){
//some code
}**else{
insert newinvoicepolicy;
  p=new Pagereference('/'+newinvoicepolicy.Id);
}
p.setredirect(true);
return p;
}

}
```

My Test class is

```
public static testmethod void policyTest(){

        Invoice_policy__c newinvoice = new invoice_policy__c(Name='Invoice',internal_alerts__c=true,American_express__c = true);
        insert newinvoice;
apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().put('invoiceid',newinvoice.id);
apexpages.standardcontroller controller;
        democlass policy = new democlass(controller);
        policy.saveIn();
}
```

Here I can't cover the invoiceid!=null part.wat should I do to achieve it

Comment: I have the same issue. but my constructor is default constructor. public PhotoUploadController() {
.................. }

Answer (score 2):

Add the below code before calling initializing the demoClass.

`Apexpages.standardcontroller controller = new Apexpages.standardcontroller(newinvoice);
democlass policy = new democlass(controller);
policy.saveIn();`

Comment: nothing was changed....it's not covering the remaining part

Comment: which part are you not able to cover? the "If" part or the "else" part ? with the above lines, you will be able to cover "if" part of the code. To cover else part, you will have to mention `apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().put('invoiceid',null);` after and reinituialise the class.

Comment: `if(invoiceid!=null){//code }`  This part

Comment: There you are - change the parameter name that you are passing. `apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().put('id',newinvoice.id);`

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake in your test class

```
apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().put('invoiceid',newinvoice.id);
```

It needs to be

```
apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().put('id',newinvoice.id);
```